# c# winforms Error provider issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck with trying to display two error mssgs for one textbox
1. if textbox empty -mssg please enter value..this works ok for me
2.text box to accept only numeric values 
Any help much appreciated
thank you
here is my code: scroll down for actual errorprovider attempt

```
ListClass lc = new ListClass();

private void btnAddStu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string title = cboTitle.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string fname = txtFname.Text;
        string lname = txtLname.Text;
        string dob = dtpDOB.Text;
        int stuId = int.Parse(txtSid.Text);
        string status = cboStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string phone = txtPhone.Text;
        string email = txtEmail.Text;


        lblRemarks.Text = lc.AddStudent(title, fname, lname, dob, stuId, status, phone, email);


        txtEmail.Clear();
        txtFname.Clear();
        txtLname.Clear();
        txtPhone.Clear();
        txtSid.Clear();
```

Errorprovide code:

```
private void txtSid_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
        bool can = false;
        int sid = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSid.Text))
        {

            ep1.SetError(txtSid, "Please Enter Student ID");
            can = true;
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(txtSid.Text, out sid))
        {
            ep1.SetError(txtSid, "Student ID must be a number");
            can = true;
        }
        e.Cancel = can;
}
```

Comment: Your `else if` condition rejects sucessfully `.TryParse`d input - you need to negate the result for your current program flow `else if (!int.TryParse([...]))`

Comment: Thank you Filbert !!It works now with "int sid=0 declared"many minutes saved ;/ all the best G

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using your event, you should try this

```
 private void textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == '.' && textIIC.Text.Contains('.'))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

                return;
            }

            e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
            decimal isNumber = 0;
            e.Handled = !decimal.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out isNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code I provide above **only allowed** you to input number, nothing but number :)